# Insulate hosted client domains from server IP address change?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I will be hosting web content for many client domains on a single IP address (with a web hosting company, not inhouse machine). Initially, I must give client some information to configure their registrar to point the domain to my server.

**I want client domains insulated from a potential IP address change**, so if I change hosts/IP address they don't have to reconfigure anything with their registrar.

Is this reasonably possible without running my own nameserver? If so, what would be the smartest way to make it happen? Instruct clients to make CNAME record? Use some type of DNS management service that clients would use as a nameserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNAME is indeed the correct way to go, you would get your clients to point there main www.domain.com record to a CNAME you setup on your domain and that should work.

However perhaps a better solution would be to manage there DNS for them by getting them to change there nameservers to servers you manage, that way you can control any IP changes much better and eliminate the (only very) slight overhead on performance that a CNAME will give

Comment: Is the CNAME still an option if I want the naked domain to resolve to my server, or is this a no-no as I have read in some cases due to MX record conflicts?

Comment: No because RFC1034 section 3.6.2 states a cname record must have no other records at that level, but for a root domain its going to have NS records which breaks that requirement, i believe with some hosts you can set a root cname but then you cant have MX records etc so no email